# kill xterm process in a bash

Tags: process, kill, xterm

I would like to kill the xterm process I started this way in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "#!/bin/bash" > /tmp/test0
grep file | awk '{print "xterm -hold -e echo",$1,"sleep 10" && pid=$!}' >> /tmp/test0
echo "exit" >> /tmp/test0
chmod 700 /tmp/test0
bash /tmp/test0&
sleep 5
kill $pid  ---> does not work
exit
```

now let's say, I have got several xterm launched this way in the same bash (test0), is there a way to store their corresponding pid in an array and call them back when it's time to kill them? Furthermore, when storing these values, is there a way to associate them with another value (in this example with $1) to make it easier to call back. nb: $1 = text

thank you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the script with:

```
bash /tmp/test0&
```

you're starting an entirely separate `bash` process and putting it in the background. You can't see the variables defined in that script; they belong to the other process. If you want to get access to variables defined in another file, load that file into your current `bash` process using the [`.` or `source` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_002e):

```
. /tmp/test0
```

After that, you'll be able to say `$pid` in your main script and get the value that was set in the other file.

---

All of that said — the way you're structuring things is very puzzling. The script you've posted has a lot of other errors that I assume are from editing the real one down for the question (you use `$!` as though it's an `awk` variable, but then expect the variable you copied it into to be defined in the Bash script, for example, and `test0` would have many syntax errors). `$!` is only defined in Bash [after a background process is run with &](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_0021-1): even if your `awk` command worked, `$pid` would be empty. If you want to get a hold of the `xterm` process's PID in that way, you need to run it as `xterm ... &`. `bash /tmp/test0 &` puts the `test0` script in the background, rather than the `xterm` command.

It seems like you'd be better off getting rid of `test0` altogether, and just launching `xterm` from the main script. **It's probably worth having a rethink about how you're going about things at a higher level**. At the very least, look at what's in your real `test0` file and see whether it's what you actually want.

Comment: IFS=','
tab=($(grep pattern file | awk '{print "xterm -hold -e echo something",$1,"&",","}'))
for i in "${tab[@]}"
do : 
 eval $i 
done
IFS=$OIFS
b=$(grep pattern file | wc -l)
i=0
ps au | grep xterm | awk '{print $2}' | while read -r PID && [[ $i -ne $b ]] 

do 
 ARRAY[$i]=$PID
 echo "ARRAY[$i]=" 
 echo ${ARRAY[$i]}
 ((i++))

done;

sure it could be smarter but it does work !

Answer (score 0):

(Your bash script doesn't run, there are errors).

So, why is the pid not killed? Is it the wrong pid? Or maybe do you need to force it's  killing using `kill -9`?

Then, use `pgrep` to get the pids. Create a new xterm and store the pid in xtermPid_1:

```
$ xtermPid_1=$(pgrep --newest xterm)
```

(look at the man pages of pgrep, it's a nice tool)